# Submodules with Dagger and AndroidInjectors

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I have been Dagger with the pre Android Injector style for a while, and have now decided to try the new methods. Til now, I was basically declaring on `AppComponent` like this:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
        modules = [ApplicationModule::class,
            NetModule::class,
            ApiModule::class,
            AnalyticsModule::class,
            DbModule::class,
            RepositoryModule::class,
            InteractorModule::class]
)
interface ApplicationComponent {
    fun inject(app: MyApp)
    fun plus(controllerModule: ControllerModule): ControllerComponent
}
```

Then I would inject my `Activities`/`Fragments`/`Services`/`Dialogs` like this:

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
...
    val component by lazy {
            (application as MyApp)
                    .applicationComponent
                    .plus(
                            ControllerModule(this)
                    )
        }

    override fun inject() {
            component.inject(this)
        }
...
}
```

Basically I had one top level app component with app-traversal modules, then an activity level component (`ControllerComponent`) with per-activity instances, common to all activities.

Now that I switched to the new methods, I create my component like so:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
        modules = [
            AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
            AppModule::class,
            NetModule::class,
            ApiModule::class,
            AnalyticsModule::class,
            DbModule::class,
            RepositoryModule::class,
            InteractorModule::class
        ]
)
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<SoulpicksApp> {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        fun build(): AppComponent
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: SoulpicksApp): Builder
    }

}
```

Make my app extend `DaggerApplication`:

```
open class MyApp : DaggerApplication() {


    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> = DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).build()

}
```

And my `Activities`/`Fragments` extend `DaggerAppCompatActivty`/`DaggerFragment` respectively:

```
class MyActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity() {

...
}
```

I understand this should automatically wire up all the activities dependencies, provided Dagger is properly set up. However I havent declared my `ControllerModule`/`Component` so of course when running my app I get:

```
e: /Users/user/dev/my-android/app/build/generated/source/kapt/devDebug/com/myapp/android/di/activity/ActivityBinder_ContributesMyActivity.java:28: error: @Subcomponent.Builder is missing setters for required modules or subcomponents: [com.myapp.android.di.controller.ControllerModule]
```

I understand previously I was creating this component on each `Activity` by using the plus() method and injecting explicitly (which is what I am trying to avoid here), how can I do that now?

Also, I have some `BottomSheetDialogFragments` and `JobServiceIntents` in my app, and theres no equivalent `DaggerBottomSheedDialogFragments`/`DaggerJobServiceIntents` to extend from, how can I work around that?

ControllerModule:

```
@Module
class ControllerModule(val activity: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity) {

    @Provides
    @ControllerScope
    fun context(): Context = activity

    @Provides
    @ControllerScope
    fun activity() = activity

    @Provides
    @ControllerScope
    fun layoutInflater() = activity.layoutInflater

    @Provides
    @ControllerScope
    fun fragmentManager(): androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager = activity.supportFragmentManager

    @Provides
    @ControllerScope
    fun provideNavigationController(activity: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity, analyticsManager: AnalyticsCompositeManager) = NavigationController(activity, analyticsManager)

    @Provides
    @ControllerScope
    fun providePackageUtils(activity: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity) : PackageUtils = PackageUtilsImpl(activity)
}
```

Changes after @luis_cortes answer:

package io.soulpicks.android.di.activity

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBinder {

    @ControllerScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [ControllerModule::class])
    abstract fun constributesSplashActivity(): SplashActivity

    @ControllerScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [ControllerModule::class])
    abstract fun contributesDashboardActivity(): DashboardActivity

    ....


}
```

ControllerModule:

```
@Module(includes = [ViewContainerModule::class])
class ControllerModule {


    @Provides
    @ControllerScope
    fun context(activity: DaggerAppCompatActivity): Context = activity.applicationContext

    @Provides
    @ControllerScope
    fun layoutInflater(activity: DaggerAppCompatActivity) : LayoutInflater = activity.layoutInflater

    @Provides
    @ControllerScope
    fun fragmentManager(activity: DaggerAppCompatActivity): FragmentManager = activity.supportFragmentManager

    @Provides
    @ControllerScope
    fun navigationController(activity: DaggerAppCompatActivity, analyticsManager: AnalyticsCompositeManager): NavigationController = NavigationController(activity, analyticsManager)

    @Provides
    @ControllerScope
    fun providePackageUtils(activity: DaggerAppCompatActivity): PackageUtils = PackageUtilsImpl(activity)
}
```

Error:

```
e: /Users/kelmer/dev/myapp-android/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/devDebug/io/myapp/android/di/application/AppComponent.java:8: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.myapp.android.managers.PackageUtils cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract interface AppComponent extends dagger.android.AndroidInjector<com.myapp.android.MyApp> {
                ^
      com.myapp.android.managers.PackageUtils is injected at
          com.myapp.android.ui.invite.SendInviteViewModel(packageUtils, …)
      com.myapp.android.ui.invite.SendInviteViewModel is injected at
          com.myapp.android.di.viewmodel.ViewModelModule.sendInviteViewModel$app_devDebug(sendInviteViewModel)
      java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is injected at
          com.myapp.android.di.viewmodel.MyappViewModelFactory(viewModels)
      com.myapp.android.di.viewmodel.MyappViewModelFactory is injected at
          com.myapp.android.di.viewmodel.ViewModelModule.bindViewModelFactory$app_devDebug(factoryMyapp)
      androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory is injected at
          com.myapp.android.base.BaseActivity.viewModelFactory
      com.myapp.android.ui.splash.SplashActivity is injected at
          dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [com.myapp.android.di.application.AppComponent → com.myapp.android.di.activity.ActivityBinder_ConstributesSplashActivity.SplashActivitySubcomponent]
  It is also requested at:
      com.myapp.android.ui.dashboard.friends.contact.ContactSyncViewModel(…, packageUtils, …)
      com.myapp.android.views.appchoosedialog.AppChooserViewModel(packageUtils)
  The following other entry points also depend on it:
      dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [com.myapp.android.di.application.AppComponent → com.myapp.android.di.activity.ActivityBinder_ContributesDashboardActivity.DashboardActivitySubcomponent]
```

https://github.com/kelmer44/mvvm-base

branch `master` is current implementation (no dagger-android)
branch `chore/dagger-rework` is my attempt

Comment: Would you mind posting the code for `ControllerModule`?

Comment: @luis_cortes just did!

Comment: Sorry one more thing. Where is your `MyActivity` subcomponent? Or are you using `@ContributesAndroidInjector`? 

If you are using `@ContributesAndroidInjector`, in what module did you put it in?

Comment: I dont have any `MyActivity` subcomponent. I only have `ControllerComponent`, which is instantiated per `Activity`, but contains activity-traversal instances (declared in `ControllerModule`). For instance, my NavigationController governs the navigation between different screens. It requires an activity instance to operate.

Comment: BTW I based my implementation on TechYourChance's tutorial on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cx6pCIbOqtI

Comment: This is helpful. Thanks.
With `dagger.android` you'll need to create a subcomponent for `MyActivity` and tie it to your `AppComponent` as a child subcomponent.

The simplest way to do this is to use the `ContributesAndroidInjector` annotation. For example: 
`@ContributesAndroidInjector abstract MyActivity contributesMyActivity();`
This would go in a module that is installed on your `AppComponent`

Comment: But then how can i bind all those instances in ControllerModule to all my activities without duplicating this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

I managed to get the sample project working with some very minor tweaks to the original solution. I've updated the answer below for posterity and marked steps that are new or have changed in bold.

**Note:** There were some very small tweaks necessary to the `ControllerModule` in the sample project that were also necessary, but the answers below are what would be most applicable to everyone else on the site so I chose to omit them here.

---

- **Create a file called `MainActivityModule` with this in it:**

```
@Module
abstract class MainActivityModule {
   @Binds @ControllerScope
   abstract fun bindsActivity(mainActivity: MainActivity): FragmentActivity
}
```

- **Add this to a module that is installed on your AppComponent:**

```
@ContributesAndroidInjector([ControllerModule::class, MainActivityModule::class])
@ControllerScope 
abstract fun contributesMyActivity(): MyActivity
```

- Remove `val activity: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity` as a property on the constructor for `ControllerModule`
- Change your `@Provides` methods to take in a `FragmentActivity` like this:

```
@Provides
@ControllerScope
fun providesContext(activity: FragmentActivity): Context = activity
```

For your other classes it just depends on whether or not you control when and how they get instantiated. If you do, just use regular constructor injection.

Comment: Sadly dagger is being unable to resolve the dependencies on ControllerModule like this :(

Comment: What is the exact error? Also can you post your new code?

Comment: Is `PackageUtils` the only dependency that can't be satisfied? 

Might be best for you to throw up a project on GitHub at this point. 

One other thing, you should just use constructor injection on `PackageUtils` and `NavigationController`.

Comment: I will try to set up a github project with the minimal classes. How could I do construction injection in those classes if they depend on each individual activity? If I do `PackageUtils(@Inject val activity: Context)`, how would dagger know which activity to inject?

Comment: I believe scopes will take care of this. 
From the docs:
>But SiblingComponentOne and SiblingComponentTwo can both use @ChildScope because there is no way to confuse a binding in one with a binding of the same type in another.

Comment: I just happened to have a mvvm base with my previous implementation of dagger, so I converted it to my best attempt at dagger-android, its at https://github.com/kelmer44/mvvm-base, branch name is `chore/dagger-rework` (`master` has current implementation)

Comment: I have forked your repo and will throw up a PR which contains all of the fixes + some niceties I added.

Comment: Here's the PR which contains all the fixes for anyone interested.

https://github.com/kelmer44/mvvm-base/pull/1

Comment: Thanks for your invaluable help @luis_cortes, however i have a question. Is it mandatory to create a module per activity/fragment? What I wanted to avoid is having too much boilerplate code, this is the reason I created a single ControllerModule for all activities/fragments. I am granting you the bounty already either way.

Comment: Thanks for your invaluable help @luis_cortes, however i have a question. Is it mandatory to create a module per activity/fragment? What I wanted to avoid is having too much boilerplate code, this is the reason I created a single ControllerModule for all activities/fragments. I am granting you the bounty already either way.

Comment: I'm not sure there's another way to do exactly what you're doing here without binding the activity in this way. 
"What I wanted to avoid is having too much boilerplate code" I suggest you watch [this talk](https://jakewharton.com/helping-dagger-help-you/) by Jake Wharton where he helps us understand what is and isn't boilerplate.

Comment: Up until this point I've tried to remain unopinionated but since we've made it this far I will say the following:
- Please look at more modern ways of incorporating dagger 2 into your application. I am not a fan of the approach presented in that video for a number of reasons. I suggest you follow [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/dagger-android) as a template instead.
- The added verbosity stems from following some patterns presented in the original video which are no longer necessary with modern androidx libs and use an older version of dagger.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at that! It's hard to find good examples/tutorials that are not outdated since the API and good practices have changed so much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196477/discussion-between-luis-cortes-and-gabriel-sanmartin).